# How to create a google sheet button that toggles a cell true/false

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a drawing of a button in google sheets. I want to assign that button to a script that toggles a specific cell between true and false. How would I do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the answer (thanks to helpful hints from another posted question):

    function changeState() {
     var a=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38').getValue();
     a=!a;
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38').setValue(a);
    };

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer (thanks to helpful hints from another posted question):

```
function changeState() {
 var a=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38').getValue();
 a=!a;
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D38').setValue(a);
};
```